# Eclipse always shows private members in Content Assist

Tags: eclipse, content-assist

For quite a while now, as soon as I attach the JDK source code in Eclipse Content Assist lists all private members of classes I use as well. Without attaching the source I don't have the documentation and argument names, but with I get plenty of stuff listed I cannot access anyway.

The checkbox »Hide proposals not visible in the invocation context« in Properties > Java > Editor > Content Assist is already checked. Am I overlooking some setting?

Eclipse Classic here in a current version, but this behavior is in the Eclipse for Java developers as well, and in the past few versions too.

Comment: That's very weird since the `Hide proposals not visible in the invocation context` checkbox seems to do the trick for me. The fact that you are seeing this in other eclipse instances is probably because you are using the same workspace, where the preferences are getting stored.

Comment: @dimitri: Found it. The `.settings` for the project somehow explicitly disabled the setting and this is nowhere exposed in the UI. Manually setting it to `enabled` works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it. The `.settings` for the project somehow explicitly disabled the setting and this is nowhere exposed in the UI. Manually setting it to `enabled` works.